# Cuando hago un update de una tabla de mi BD se actualiza pero cuando hago un select desde Java lo trae sin actualizar

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con JSP, Java y con Mysql y tengo el siguiente problema.
Tengo una tabla en la cual añado un objeto y cuando la llevo a actualizar y consulto a través del cliente de Mysql veo que ha hecho el update sin problemas pero cuando voy a traer lo que es la tabla de nuevo para  java con los datos actualizados por algún motivo sigue teniendo los datos antiguos. Refresco la pagina para que haga el select de nuevo y sigue trayendo los datos anteriores al update. La única forma de que traiga los nuevos es lanzando de nuevo el proyecto.

```
public class GestionAddGames {
    
    private EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("WebPU");
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }
    
    public void altaAnyadir(int id_juego, int id_lista, String estado) {
        AddGames add = new AddGames(id_juego, id_lista, estado);
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(add);
        tx.commit();
    }
    
    public List<AddGames> traerAdd(){
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<AddGames> qr = em.createQuery("Select u from AddGames u", AddGames.class);
        List<AddGames> add = qr.getResultList();
        for (int i = 0; i < add.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(add.get(i).getEstado());
        }
  
        return add;
    } 
    
    public void ModificarEstado(int id_add, int id_lista, int id_juego, String estado) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        System.out.println(estado);
        String jpql = "Update AddGames Set id_game = ?1, id_games_list = ?2, estado = ?3 Where id_add_games = ?4";
        TypedQuery<AddGames> qr = em.createQuery(jpql, AddGames.class);
        qr.setParameter(1, id_juego);
        qr.setParameter(2, id_lista);
        qr.setParameter(3, estado);
        qr.setParameter(4, id_add);
        qr.executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();
    }
}
```

Los metodos que importan son el de `trarAdd()` y `ModificarEstado()`, en el primero nada mas ejecutarlo recorro la lista y muestro los estados porque son los que me interan ya que el objetivo es que pueda modificar eso.

Si hace falta que adjunte el codigo jsp donde se ve cuando se invocan los metodos ponerlo, pero es que cuando hago el update me actualiza la bd pero por algun motivo cuando hace el select no trae los datos bien.
Cualquier ayuda se agradece

Comment: Eh, suena a que no estás haciendo commit de las transacciones...

Comment: Si que hace commit porque sino en la base de datos no actualizaria los datos el problema es al traerlos de nuevo y que los traiga desactualizados

Comment: Cada operación puede usar una conexión diferente y no sabemos cómo las estás manejando.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el manejo de las sesiones que tengas abiertas, te recomiendo que uses Hibernate. te dan esas opciones de manejo de las sesiones en automático o que tu las manipules.

Comment: No si por mi fuera estaria usando Sts con Hibernate y el editor de plantillas de Thymeleaf, pero empece el proyecto con esto y con el tiempo que tenia no me podia echar atras

Answer (score 0):

Adjunto a continuacion la parte jsp donde se da uso a esos metodos y donde se puede apreciar que el select se lleva a cabo siempre antes de mostrar los datos.

```
<div>
        <nav>
            <form name="seleccion" method="post">
                <input type="submit" name="jugados" value="Jugado">
                <input type="submit" name="jugando" value="Jugando">
                <input type="submit" name="pendientes" value="Pendiente">
            </form>
        </nav>
        <ul class="navega">
            <%
                GestionJuegos gJuego = new GestionJuegos();
                GestionAddGames gAdGestionJuegos = new GestionAddGames();
                GestionListaJuegos gLJuegos = new GestionListaJuegos();

                List<Juego> juegos = gJuego.traerJuegos();
                List<ListaJuegos> listas = gLJuegos.traerListas();
                List<AddGames> adds = gAdGestionJuegos.traerAdd();

                ListaJuegos lista = new ListaJuegos();
                Juego juego = new Juego();
                Usuario u = (Usuario) session.getAttribute("usuario");

                for (int i = 0; i < listas.size(); i++) {
                    if (listas.get(i).getId_user() == u.getId_user()) {
                        lista = listas.get(i);
                    }
                }
                if (request.getParameter("jugados") == null && request.getParameter("jugando") == null && request.getParameter("pendientes") == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < adds.size(); i++) {
                        if (adds.get(i).getEstado().contentEquals("Jugado")) {
                            if (adds.get(i).getId_games_list() == lista.getId()) {
                                juego.setId_game(adds.get(i).getId_game());
                                for (int j = 0; j < juegos.size(); j++) {
                                    if (juegos.get(j).getId_game() == juego.getId_game()) {
                                        out.print("<li><a href=\"juego.jsp?juego=");
                                        out.print(juegos.get(j).getNombre());
                                        out.print("\"><img src=\"images/" + juegos.get(j).getCaratula() + "\" width=\"150\" height=\"200\"></a>");
                                        out.print("</li>");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (request.getParameter("jugados") != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < adds.size(); i++) {
                        if (adds.get(i).getEstado().contentEquals("Jugado")) {
                            if (adds.get(i).getId_games_list() == lista.getId()) {
                                juego.setId_game(adds.get(i).getId_game());
                                for (int j = 0; j < juegos.size(); j++) {
                                    if (juegos.get(j).getId_game() == juego.getId_game()) {
                                        out.print("<li><a href=\"juego.jsp?juego=");
                                        out.print(juegos.get(j).getNombre());
                                        out.print("\"><img src=\"images/" + juegos.get(j).getCaratula() + "\" width=\"150\" height=\"200\"></a>");
                                        out.print("</li>");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (request.getParameter("jugando") != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < adds.size(); i++) {

                        if (adds.get(i).getEstado().contentEquals("Jugando")) {
                            if (adds.get(i).getId_games_list() == lista.getId()) {
                                juego.setId_game(adds.get(i).getId_game());
                                for (int j = 0; j < juegos.size(); j++) {
                                    if (juegos.get(j).getId_game() == juego.getId_game()) {
                                        out.print("<li><a href=\"juego.jsp?juego=");
                                        out.print(juegos.get(j).getNombre());
                                        out.print("\"><img src=\"images/" + juegos.get(j).getCaratula() + "\" width=\"150\" height=\"200\"></a>");
                                        out.print("</li>");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (request.getParameter("pendientes") != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < adds.size(); i++) {
                        if (adds.get(i).getEstado().contentEquals("Pendiente")) {
                            if (adds.get(i).getId_games_list() == lista.getId()) {
                                juego.setId_game(adds.get(i).getId_game());
                                for (int j = 0; j < juegos.size(); j++) {
                                    if (juegos.get(j).getId_game() == juego.getId_game()) {
                                        out.print("<li><a href=\"juego.jsp?juego=");
                                        out.print(juegos.get(j).getNombre());
                                        out.print("\"><img src=\"images/" + juegos.get(j).getCaratula() + "\" width=\"150\" height=\"200\"></a>");
                                        out.print("</li>");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            %>
        </ul>
        <a href="ControllerUsuario?op=toModificarUsuario">Modificar datos de usuario</a>
```